# Iterating over API calls and write to csv

Tags: python, api, csv

I have a dataframe (df) with 700k names of songs and artist and I use this list to retrieve song lyrics from LyricWikia. However, I can only ask for 5000 songs at a time.

I want to run a query capped at 5000 calls multiple times and output the result into one or multiple csvs.

I now have a piece of code that just download until I reach the cap of 5000. I want it to stop just before 5000 and rerun the code and append it to the existing csv (or dataframe). So basically a for loop that skips again in the dataframe with the artists and song names.

```
with open('lyrics-4.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for i, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(), 1): 
        lyrics = []
        artist = row[2]
        song = row[3]
        try:
            lyrics = lyricwikia.get_lyrics(artist, song)
        except:
            pass
        writer.writerow([artist,song,lyrics])
```

Comment: `with open('lyrics-4.csv', 'a+') as csv_file` That's all it is. Change the mode.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you're using pandas. Why not work with the data frame and then dump to csv?

Comment: sorry. I want to download the 5000 and then run it again and download another 5000. This part is missing in the code.

Comment: Then, just change the mode like I mentioned.

Comment: The mode only appends it to the existing file, right? I need it to run again and skip ahead in the df file.

Comment: `a+` creates the file if it doesn't exist, and appends if it does. 
Skip ahead = append... if this isn't what you want, you'll need to clarify your intent.

Comment: I'll edit the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153659/discussion-between-melvin-wevers-and-cs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a for loop to break into chunks of 5000 and just use pandas to directly write to csv?

```
for i in range(N):
    # api call to acquire 5000 songs to dataframe called df here
    df['lyrics'] = lyricwikia.get_lyrics(df['artist'], df['song'])
    df.to_csv('lyrics'+str(i)+'.csv')
```

Alternatively if you want to append to the same csv file:

```
for i in range(N):
    # api call to acquire 5000 songs to dataframe called df here
    df['lyrics'] = lyricwikia.get_lyrics(df['artist'], df['song'])
    df.to_csv('lyrics.csv', mode='a')
```

EDIT:

```
for i in range(0, len(df), 5000):    
    df_chunk = df[i : i+5000]
    df_chunk['lyrics'] = lyricwikia.get_lyrics(df_chunk['artist'], df_chunk['song'])
    df_chunk.to_csv('lyrics.csv', mode='a')
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the breaking into chunks of 5000. I'm using itertuples to go through the rows, but I don't know how to do this in chunks of 5000 that follow each other.

Comment: You could pre-chunk the master dataframe into chunks of 5000. Add a time delay if there are API all limits. See the edited answer